# Collecting cookies that are not set by HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, http, cookies

I need to scrape a table of info from a site for which I have valid credentials because the owners of the site do not provide an API.

I performed a login and saved the traffic with Fiddler, and am trying to replicate the key steps.
I'm going to show the steps I've done so far, and get to where I am stuck.

#### Log into the base url

```
CookieContainer jar = new CookieContainer();
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlBase);
request.CookieContainer = jar;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
newUrl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
```

Along with the return a cookie is set. When I look at the `CookieContainer` it has a count of 1 after the call.
Interestingly the response object does not contain the cookie - but I think all is okay because I can use `jar`.

#### 2nd call

I'm not yet at the page where the name and password are presented, that doesn't happen until the 4th call.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlBase + 
secondCallFolderAddition);

CookieCollection bakery = new CookieCollection();

request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", @"1");
//request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.57";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp, image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string newURL = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
```

I get an OK status, and the response looks good compared to the original Fiddler traffic capture. In the original this 2nd call does not set a cookie, and no cookie is set here.

#### Third call

But here's where I get lost: the browser sent cookie data with three values (I've obfuscated):

```
__utma=1.123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.1
olfsk=olfsk12345678901234567890123456789
hblid=abCDl11ABCabXabc1aABv1FLFX1RE1OS
```

I don't know where those values get set. They seem to relate to Google Analytics (from articles I've found) but I don't know how to collect them so that I can attach them to the call I make.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newUrl);

request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.57";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;
 q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";

request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br");
request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8");

///request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, 
@"__utma=1.123456789.123456789.123456789.123456789.1; 
olfsk=olfsk12345678901234567890123456789; 
hblid=abCDl11ABCabXabc1aABv1FLFX1RE1OS");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

string newURL = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
```

Please note the commented out line with the cookie data - I've tried this with that line un-commented also.

What happens is that **I never get a response to the call**.

I am very appreciative of any insights.
I am guessing that the cookie data in the third call is needed, and that is is set by a client-side script that gets collected between the 2nd and 3rd call - but I am new to this and unsure.
Also - if it is set on the client side, how can I get valid cookies that will get me past this roadblock. (These is another roadblock coming in the next call, where more cookies are used that i do not see set in a server response - but i am not there yet.)

I know I can solve this by using a `WebBrowser` object, but that seems like a clumsy solution.  Is there a less clumsy way to go? Are there other objects or libraries I should try?  (RestSharp? Postman? Webrequest object instead of HTTPWeRequest?)

Comment: After thinking about this my current idea is to go back to the html page where these cookies are probably set (cookies that are not set from the http response), and to look for the script.  The to replicate the script as a function in c#, and add the data generated to the request call (to be more precise,it will be the third of my calls). If anyone knows of a better way, please let me know.